# how to combine java.util.Calendar and HQL Between

Tags: java, hql, between

I'm trying to get the books that were loaned between two dates.
Since data has the lovely 2009 is shown as 109 feature I decided to use calendars.

However when writing my HQL I ran into the problem that BETWEEN doesn't view a Calendar as a date.
Now I'm wondering if there's a solution for this.
Or am I stuck writing functions in my class to get the hour, day, month, year and write a long where statement?

`query = session.createQuery("from model.Book book where book.loaned between :earliest and :latest");`

The problem is that the between only works with a date object. and loaned is  Javva.Util.Calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a `Date` from a `Calendar` using `Calendar.getTime` - does that help you? You may run into time zone issues if you're not careful, admittedly... how exactly are the dates stored in the database?

Comment: You can use getTime in a java class, but you can't do so in HQL.

Comment: Okay, I'm confused as to how you're calling this then... I thought you were passing in the arguments to the query. Could you give some sample code in your question to make it clearer? I suspect I may not be able to help, but hopefully someone else can.

Comment: query = session.createQuery("from model.Book book where book.loaned between :earliest and :latest").

The problem is that the between only works with a date object. and loaned is Java.Util.Calendar.
There might be another way to get the books between the two dates, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Please edit that code into your question - it'll make it easier for everyone reading the question. However, I would suggest that book.loaned should probably be a java.util.Date; you can add an extra (non-persistent) property to get it as a calendar.

Comment: Can you rewrite it to use less/greater, e.g. :  where book.loaned >= :earliest and book.loaned <= :latest?